# Calling a Page Method using jQuery - Backbone.Js now

Tags: javascript, jquery, model-view-controller, backbone.js, underscore.js

With the below javascript code i am trying some BackboneJs concepts. Couldn't figure out why the response after invoking a XHR request is HTML of full page rather than the serialized version of `Person class`. Have a look below
Server Side Code is of `C#` and `ASP.NET 2.0`

**note:** forget the `url`and `urlroot` on the model, i am using the backbonejs `Sync`

#### Javascript

```
window.Person = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        id: Math.random(),
        name: "Type your name"
    },
    initialize: function (model) {
        this.bind("change", this.ModelChanged);
    },
    ModelChanged: function () {

    },
    url: "CreatePerson",
    urlRoot: "/index.aspx/"
});

Backbone.sync = function (met, mod, op) {
    switch (met) {
        case "create":
            break;
        case "update":
            break;
        case "delete":
            break;
        case "read":
            break;
        default:
            break;

    }
};
```

#### Server side code

```
    [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public static Person CreatePerson(Person newPerson)
    {
        List<Person> peopleList = HttpContext.Current.Session["People"] as List<Person>;
        if (peopleList == null)
        {
            peopleList = new List<Person>();
        }
        Person p1 = new Person();
        p1 = newPerson;
        peopleList.Add(p1);
        HttpContext.Current.Session["People"] = peopleList;
        return p1;
    }
```

#### Person class

```
public class Person
{

    public string Id
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get;
        set;
    }


}
```

#### Finally the test code

```
var x = new Person({
    name: "StackOverflow"
});
$.post("index.aspx/CreatePerson", "{" + JSON.stringify(x) + "}", function () {
    console.log(arguments)
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand why but jQuery made me follow this weird procedure to get this done.

**It serializes valid json to URL encoded format & not json string which is wrong.**

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
});

Backbone.sync = function (met, mod, op) {
    console.log("method", met, "model", mod);
    switch (met) {
        case "create":
            $.post("index.aspx/CreatePerson", { "newPerson": mod.attributes }, function () { console.log(arguments) }, "json");
            break;
        case "update":
            var x = { "newPerson": mod.attributes };                
            x = JSON.stringify(x);                
            $.post("index.aspx/CreatePerson", x, function () { console.log(arguments) });
            break;
        case "delete":
            break;
        case "read":
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
};
```

Comment: Have you looked at the fiddler 2 logging for both request/responses? That will tell you exactly what is happening

Comment: @GarethElms hi yes i did look at them in firebug post details. the difference is that jquery sends a HTTP POST and URL encodes the parameters i.e DATA for the post hence `key=value&key=value` is the post data but asp.net webmethods expect a valid JSON string that can be deserialized to the final object. Hence i had to follow this strange but working procedure. But i need to point when proxy is generated through scriptmanager i can do this & it works `PageMethods.CreatePerson(model)`

Answer (score 0):

try setting the `contentType`

```
$.ajaxSetup({
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
});
```

after that your request

```
var x = new Person({
    name: "StackOverflow"
});
$.post("index.aspx/CreatePerson", "{" + JSON.stringify(x) + "}", function () {
    console.log(arguments)
});
```